# Setting an Input Box Background

Tags: css, forms, layout, input

I have to create an input box with the following background

[image]

So far in my code I have the code below and its not showing -> What would be the correct procedure to do this?

I also have a couple of variations of this button I have to produce and they are the following:

- A cross on the dark area of the button - I was just going to use a `<span>` tag with a class and set the graphic to that -> Would this be a good way to go?
- A paper clip icon just after the curve on the left ->  I was going to do the same as above -> Would this be a good way to go?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="innerTo">
        <form action="#" method="get">
           <label for="recipients">TO: </label>
              <input type="search" name="recipients" id="recipients" placeholder="Recipients Names">
    </form>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.innerBar .innerTo{
    width:200px;
    padding:5px 0 0 15px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.innerBar .innerTo label{
    margin:0 15px 0 0;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#666666;
}
.innerBar .innerTo input[type=search] {
    color: red;
}
.innerBar .recipients{
    background-image:url('../images/searchBGpng.png') no-repeat;
    width:192px;
    height:27px;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/3Dzga/):

```
<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" value="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"/>
</div>

.input-container {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vlc5.png) no-repeat;
    width:197px;
    height:28px;
}
.input-container input{
    height:28px;
    line-height:28px;/*results in nice text vertical alignment*/
    border:none;
    background:transparent;
    padding:0 10px;/*don't start input text directly from the edge*/
    width:148px;/*full width - grey on the side - 2*10px padding*/
}
```

If you're planning to reuse it with different widths, you should look up the [sliding doors technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/).

Comment: Thanks o.v.  Have I got the correct approach for my variations?

Comment: @JessMcKenzie: seeing how you elected to use `type="search"`, you should be OK with using pseudo-elements rather than hardcoded spans etc. One of the first links that came up: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Comment: @JessMcKenzie: also - not a big fan of float soup - personally I'd set `position:relative` on the container, and absolute-positon the icons against that (you could even position icons *outside* the container element with this approach with smth like `left:-20px;`)

Comment: With line-height set to the full height of the input field, the caret will look strange in Chrome on Windows. Any ideas how to avoid that?

Comment: @damd: hmm... define "strange", or maybe add a screenshot + Chrome version#?

Comment: @o.v.: Basically, everything looks great as expected, except the cursor becomes very "tall", I'm guessing about as tall as line-height. This is version "24.0.1312.52 m" and seems to be the latest available version for me. I'm afraid I can't provide screenshots in this case.

Comment: @damd: I'd play around with maybe the top- and bottom- padding on the input (i.e. +4px padding, -4px line-height) but otherwise wouldn't get too hung up on it, just an imo

Answer (score 0):

I have created new code for your form if you like this, then go ahead and apply it to your html code

**You can do this**

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="#" method="get">
           <label for="recipients">TO: </label>
              <input type="search" name="recipients" id="recipients" placeholder="Recipients Names">
    <input type="submit" value="">
    </form>
```

**Css Code**

```
label{
float:left;
    margin:25px 0 0 0px;
    padding:0;
}

input[type="search"], input[type="submit"]{
margin:20px 0 0 0px;
    padding:0;
     line-height:28px;
    height:28px;
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vlc5.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    border: 0 none;
    float:left;
}

input[type="search"]{
width:152px;
    padding-left:15px;
}

input[type="submit"]{
background-position:-167px 0;
    width: 30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Live demo link here http://jsfiddle.net/AL6vb/4/

Now change to code according your layout this is only demo .......