# jquery ui date picker with default text in textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

is there any way we can have a default text value (not some date but some sort of label, which is displayed inside textbox, but gets changed to selected date if the user selects some date.

```
// I want the MM/DD/YYYY to be displayed inside text box if no date is selected by user

    <input id="datePicker" value ="MM/DD/YYYY">
    $(function() { 
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( )});
```

I tried adding a dummy input box with mm/dd/yyyy and showing and hiding the same using focus and blur methods, but its not working, properly.
Is there any elegant way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.
PS: I am not using html5 and i need this thing to be working in ie 8 ,9.
it should look something like this
[image: text box sample]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add `placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"` inside your `<input>`,

`<input id="datePicker" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"`>

Comment: Thanks for the input since i am not using html5 and i need this solution to be working in ie8 and 9 as well. So place holder would not help me.

Comment: I see, in that case you can use a jQuery plugin such as this [jQuery Placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) :)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this plugin, and let you know.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the heads up and it worked like a charm in IE 8 and IE 9 after using this plugin. I am accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside script tags of the HTML page (or onload).  This will show current date in the input box.  You may use `title="Enter MM/DD/YYYY"` in the input to show tooltip. If you really want to show MM/DD/YYYY in the text, you may use css background image property. I am not good at css, but I guess it will work (just create one small png with text MM/DD/YYYY.

```
Date.prototype.formatMMDDYYYY = function(){
        return this.getMonth() + 
        "/" +  this.getDate() +
        "/" +  this.getFullYear();
    }

    var dt = new Date();
    $('#datePicker').val(dt.formatMMDDYYYY());


        $(function() { 
        $( "#datePicker" ).datepicker( )});
```

Comment: My question is not to have a default date inside textbox but some text which is not a date. I have added a sample image.

Comment: One dirty trick I can suggest is to use style  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843966/setting-an-input-box-background

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have unified datepickers' behaviour in all your site, simply override `datepicker()` function:

```
$(function () {
    var pickerFn = $.fn.datepicker,
        placeholder = 'MM/DD/YYYY';

    $.fn.datepicker = function () {
        var datePicker = pickerFn.apply(this, arguments);  

        var self = this;
        self.attr('placeholder', placeholder);

        return datePicker;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="datePicker" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#datePicker').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false
 });
</script>
```

Comment: `input[id="datePicker"]`? What's wrong with `#datePicker`

Comment: nothing's wrong with that... I initially had in my code input[name=...] so I just copy pasted it and modify to match the example... i modified it :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have got this solution, init with text type, on click change to date input:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var birthdateInput = $("#details-date");
    // Init
    birthdateInput.attr({
        "type": "text",
        "placeholder": "Birthdate"
    });
    // Detect clic
    birthdateInput.on("click", function () {
        // Verifica input type
        if ($(this).attr("type") === "text") {
            // Cambia a tipo date
            $(this).attr("type", "date");
        }
    });

    // Verify is not empty
    birthdateInput.on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            // If empty change to text
            $(this).attr({
                "type": "text",
                "placeholder": "Birthdate"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input 
        name="birthdate" 
        id="details-date"
        class="form-control"
         type="date"
        />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```