# Change the background of the input text but not the background of whole input field

Tags: html, css, angular

Is it possible to change the background of the input text but not the whole input field? I did use the pseudo selector `::firstline` to change it, this seems to be working on chrome but not in safari, although i am conditionally using this style in angular application.
I want to be able the achieve something similar to the screenshot below.
[image]

The CSS code looks like this

```
.tag-text::first-line{
    background:#c8dadf;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Angular template is

```
<input type="text" [ngClass]="{'tag-text': some-condition}" />
```

Comment: As you can see [here](https://caniuse.com/css-first-line) safari support `firstline`, just IE don't support `firstline` with double colon

Comment: It says it's supported(checked on MDN as well) but the background is not appearing on safari. I am starting to feel like, the issue may be is with the focus selector.

Comment: try to post all code.

Comment: you can fake it using div with padding and putting the input inside the div, let me know if you need the implementation

Comment: I would love to see your implementation @BesufkadMenji.

Answer (score 1):

style;

```
<style>
    body {
        display: grid;
    }

    .input-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr max-content;
        grid-column-gap: 8px;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: white;
        justify-self: left;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 0 8px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    /*you may only need this part*/
    .input {
        border: none;
        /*make it equal to your preferred font size*/
        height: 18px;
        background-color: #C8DADF;
        color: #8A8E8F;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }

    span {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        background-color: #000;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
     <!--   replace this with your search icon-->
     <span></span>
     <input type="text" class="input"/>
     <!--      replace this with your clear icon-->
     <span></span>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found a [question similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843966/setting-an-input-box-background) to yours.The only thing you need to change is the background-color.